# Gulp suddenly stopped watching changes, compiling scss to css and opening and reloading page

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch, gulp-sass, gulp-concat

I have been working on a project for a while, using Gulp for compiling SCSS to CSS (making one CSS file from several SCSS files), minifying CSS, also watching file changes and reloading page with Browser Sync.

While changing some scss and html code and not doing anything to the gulpfile and not renaming any files, page in a browser has suddenly failed and said that it cannot find a page.

I tried to reload the page with "gulp" command and it didn't help.

Now I have several problems. Gulp: 
 - stopped watching changes;
 - compiling scss to css;
 - opening and reloading page.

All these worked perfectly before this problem.

Here's my code for Gulp:

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");
var watch = require("gulp-watch");
var csso = require("gulp-csso");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

/* Static Server + watching scss/html files */
gulp.task("serve", ["sass"], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./"
    });

    gulp.watch("*.html").on("change", browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch("sass/*.scss", ["sass"]).on("change", browserSync.reload);
});

/* Compile Sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers */
gulp.task("sass", function() {
    return gulp.src("sass/*.scss")
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

/* Concatenate and minify CSS */
gulp.task("css:build", function() {
 gulp.watch("css/*.css").on("change", function() {
  return gulp.src("css/*.css")
  .pipe(concat("style.concat.css"))
  .pipe(csso({
   comments: false
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest("css_result"));
 });
});

gulp.task("default", ["serve", "css:build"]);
```

If I run "gulp" in command line now it shows this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSauj.png)

Why could it happen and what steps should I do now?

---

#### Solved

Problem's solved. There was a mistake inside one sass file. After a correction everything started working without any other changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem's solved. There was a mistake inside one sass file. After a correction everything started working without any other changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify this:

```
gulp.watch("sass/*.scss", ["sass"]).on("change", browserSync.reload);
```

to

```
gulp.watch("sass/*.scss", ["sass"]);
```

since you are already calling browserSync.stream() at the end of your 'sass' task. Also, try this instead of the browserSync.stream() call:

```
.pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
```

I assume your html file being served by browserSync has the css links produced by the 'sass' task **NOT** the css produced by the 'css:build' task.  Otherwise you will have other problems, probably race issues since your 'css:build' task is running after the 'sass' task produced css is reloaded into the browser.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Mark! I did everything you said and it still doesn't work.

My html-file uses css link that is produced by css:build (concatenated and minified version of css).

I have added one commend to scss now and this comment isn't shown in css file (neither in the original css file, nor in the minified version) after running "gulp" command.

Mystic!

Comment: Sass probably strips out the comments.  As I mentioned, change your html css link to point to the 'sass' task result - folder 'css'.  That is where you are reloading css - at the end of the 'sass' task.  So browserSync is trying to reload then, NOT after the 'css:build' task.  Otherwise, you could try moving the .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})); call to the end of the 'css:build' task and remove it from the 'sass' task.

Comment: Used the first and the second method that you have mentioned in your last comment (changing css link in html and moving .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));). It didn't help.

I see no problem in my css, html and gulp files as it all worked perfectly before. I think the problem is in npm packages or something... As the command line doesn't show the destination of the local server and doesn't watch files anymore as it was before.

I reinstalled Windows, node, npm, packages and it didn't help either.

Comment: Problem's solved. There was a mistake inside one sass file. After a correction everything started working without any other changes. Thank you for your attempts to help! Sometimes big problems are caused by small and nearly invisible mistakes...